# How to set a field value with same document id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a schema on mongoose where a field value is the same as document id.

Desired output:

```
{
 "_id": "61c75bf3b151c6c6854c83db",
 "password":"some password",
 "name":"some name",
 "linkId": "61c75bf3b151c6c6854c83db"
}
```

Here document id and linkId is same. How can I do that when creating a new document? It maybe redundant but is it possible?

Comment: i think you can create an objectID store it into a js variable, and use this variable as  value in both fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pre-hook middleware for the `save` method, when you insert any document it will clone the `_id` field in to `linkId` field,

```
// SCHEMA
const SchemaObj = new mongoose.Schema(
    // your schema...
);

// PRE MIDDLEWARE
SchemaObj.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.linkId = this._id;
    next();
});
```